# Ubuntu is not getting booted?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on Windows 7 PC  on seperate disk partition (that is E:\ drive). Installation is complete. Now the system is always booting in windows 7. I opted for dual boot at the time of installation. But system directly booting windows without asking anything.

What is to be done next ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your BIOS is set to boot from the Windows 7 partition/drive and not the partition that has GRUB / Ubuntu.

Comment: What is the solution ? Windows partions is on C:\ Ubuntu partition is on E:\ drive. Kindly tell me how to set this.

Comment: If you only have one hard drive, check out mondjunge's post.  If Ubuntu and Windows are on different hard drives, it might be that your BIOS is telling your computer at boot time to look at the wrong harddrive.
You enter the BIOS when the computer first boots.  Normally there is a splash screen telling you to press F2 or the delete key (or some other key) to enter the BIOS.  There should be an entry in there to tell you your computer which device to boot from (hardrives, floppy, cdrom, usb, network etc.).  You would want to choose the drive that Ubuntu is installed to in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you need to boot up the live ubuntu CD/DVD and rewrite the MBR.

This is a simple task, but is best be done with some fundamental understanding of partitions, partitioning and how booting works basically.

Just steps:

- boot in live mode via ubuntu live CD
- open up a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)
- run following command:

  `sudo grub-setup /dev/sdX`

where X is the letter for the Hard Disk to write the MBR to. Usually this is sda, but it could be sdb or sdc in your case.

If you installed your System with the WUBI installer, be aware that this solution might not work. I am not familiar with WUBI.